# Teacher giving very low grades to students

Tags: single-word-requests

What term can be used for a teacher that gives very low grades to students? Is "greedy " applicable ? " greedy teacher"?

Comment: What grade would this teacher give if the student answered all the questions correctly?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of StackExchange is that you demonstrate your attempts at initial research. Looking up *greedy* in the dictionary, for example, should tell you that it does not make any sense to use here, as the teacher is not withholding high grades in order to keep them for himself. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: The greedy teacher withheld her students' grades and added them to her own account. She was taught a lesson by the Principal who withheld Teacher's grades and added to **his** account! Moreover, the teacher was severely down-voted by her students on EL&U for being greedy and parsimonious. (Clue: 'parsimonious' = stingy or miserly -- a good word for a teacher who gives all the students low grades! )

Comment: In Kerala,India the gentlemen teachers are called 'Master' and lady teachers are called 'Teacher.' Younger lady teachers are sometimes referred to as 'Miss' as in "the Miss dictated exercises to the students." Principal is usually nicknamed 'Princy.'

Answer (score 3):

Greedy is not the right word, but some teachers who always give low grades (and no praise) have been described as **stingy**, **parsimonious** and **miserly**, which have the same meaning.

Example:

She is stingy with her grades and miserly with her praise.

He is generous with his sarcasm but parsimonious with his grades.

In spite of their good work, their scores were poor, because the teacher was miserly.

(Miserly is also used in cricket to describe bowlers who do not concede many runs to the batsmen!)

Answer (score 3):

Hard/tough grader

Please [check](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grader)

http://forums.atozteacherstuff.com/index.php?threads/hard-graders.46101/

[What Students Say about a Hard Grader](http://ualr.edu/epmoore/crsevals.html)

Answer (score -6):

scathing, condescending, harsh, ruthless, unforgiving, dismissive, prejudiced?

Comment: This answer would be strengthened by explaining what those terms mean, how they would suit the OP's scenario, and how they differ from one another. Otherwise, this is little more than a thesaurus would provide.